# Compiling error VBA macro taken from internet

Tags: vba

I took this code from the internet to find an exe file on the harddrive, namely, Word, since I cannot find it.

```
Sub FindExcelExe()
    MsgBox LocateExecutable("C:\WorkbookTest\Boktest2.xlsx")
End Sub
' **** Source - http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Excel-File-Foreground-t1982963.html
```

It complains on this code -->

```
Private Declare Function FindExecutable Lib "shell32" Alias "FindExecutableA" ( _
  ByVal lpFile As String, _
  ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
  ByVal sResult As String _
) As Long
```

<-- Error: May only exist comments after End Sub, End function....

```
Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Function LocateExecutable(PathToFile) As String

Dim lngPosition As Long
Dim lngResult As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strPathToExecutable As String

  strFile = Dir(PathToFile)
  If Len(strFile) > 0 Then
    strPath = Left$(PathToFile, Len(PathToFile) - Len(strFile))
    strPathToExecutable = Space$(MAX_PATH)

    lngResult = FindExecutable(strFile, strPath, strPathToExecutable)

    If lngResult >= 32 Then
      lngPosition = InStr(strPathToExecutable, Chr$(0))
      If lngPosition > 0 Then
        LocateExecutable = Left$(strPathToExecutable, lngPosition - 1)
      End If
    End If
  End If

End Function
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Like the error message tells you, move the `declare` statement before any `sub`s you might have.

Comment: Ok, thanks alot it now works. For some reason the author placed the variable declaration and the Declar function below the sub. Maybe it was something I missed.